# cannot call value of non-function type '(key: Int, value: CallSession)?'

Tags: ios, swift3

What is wrong with this:

```
func findCallByUUID(uuid: UUID) -> CallSession? {
    let foo = [Int: CallSession]()
    return foo.first(where: { (id: Int, session: CallSession) in
        session.uuid == uuid
    })
}
```

Okay I don't need `id` but I want to know how to use `first` with a Dictionary.

This works fine:

```
return foo.values.first(where: { (session) in session.uuid == uuid })
```

Comment: Dictionary shouldn't be ordered, so there is not really a "first".

Comment: @Larme `first` _is_ available in Swift dictionaries (it passes a tuple with a key & value for each element to the filter)...

Comment: One problem I can spot in your snippet, is that you are supposed to return a `CallSession?`, but you return a `(key: Int, value: CallSession)?` (a key/value pair from the elements of the dictionary) instead... Maybe something like `return foo.first(where: { (id: Int, session: CallSession) in
        session.uuid == uuid
    })?.value` is what you intended to do?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alladinian

```
func findCallByUUID(uuid: UUID) -> CallSession? {
    let foo = [Int: CallSession]()
    return foo.first(where: { (id: Int, session: CallSession) in
            session.uuid == uuid
        })
        .map { (id: Int, session: CallSession) in
            session
        }
}
```